# Changing Small Image For All Products in Magento

Tags: sql, database, magento, magento-1.7

I use the sql code below, and it seems to work fine, and when I check the admin panel of magento, I see that the change is done as in the picture. However, when I check the website, I see the position 1 product still in all products as small image. Nothing seems to be changed in front end. I cleared all the caches but still the same, any ideas?

[image: magento image backend]

```
UPDATE duvargiydir_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
       duvargiydir_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
       duvargiydir_catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
AND ev.attribute_id IN (86)
AND mgv.position = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to flush the image cache located at System -> Cache Management.

You'll see a button on the bottom that says "Flush Catalog Images Cache" or something similar.

Magento will create a resized and compressed image to display on the front-end rather than the original. So if you change the original in the database the observer methods were not triggered to clear the cache and recreate the thumbs.

Doing this will allow for the thumbs to regenerate on page load.